# Tengo una función la cual no pasa de un for loop

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo  la siguiente función.

```
static Future getSliderInfo() async {
    final response = await http.get('https://ejemplo de url');
    List<Slider> sliderlist;

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List jsonReponse = json.decode(response.body);
      
      print('empezo');
      for (var post in jsonReponse) {
        
        sliderlist.add(Slider.fromJson(post));
      }
      print('termino');

      return sliderlist;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load slider');
    }
  }
```

El problema que tengo es que **nunca llega a la parte de 'termino'** y no tengo idea del porque, ya deshabilité todos los **breakpoints** que tenía el proyecto, me asegure que en el runtime lo que se está mandando en la variable jsonReponse sea en verdad una lista la cual lo es (Es una **List< dynamic >**), limpie el proyecto haciendo **flutter clean** y nada.

Comment: Hola bro, deberías de probar a poner el print dentro del bucle, quizá no esta entrando a la condición que tienes arriba y todo ese bloque mas bien no se esta ejecutando y por eso no te imprime nada.

Comment: Ya lo hice, si esta entrando, inclusive si pongo un print(post) lo imprime sin problema.

Comment: si te sirvió la respuesta, márcala como solucionada

Answer (score -1):

Es un error básico, si te fijas bien, estás usando `List<Slider> sliderlist;` sin inicializarlo, es decir es nulo al inicio.

Cuando haces `sliderlist.add(Slider.fromJson(post));` , `sliderList` es nulo por lo tanto tienes une error.

**Solución:**

Inicializa `sliderList` , así :

```dart
 List<Slider> sliderlist = <Slider>[];
```

Comment: Esto fue lo primero que intenté y tampoco resulto ser.

Comment: luego de print('empezo'); imprime el `jsonReponse` y actualiza tu pregunta con eso , también agrega un try catch en todo el  if (response.statusCode == 200) { ,  y pinta la excepción que sale